# Passage from $\mathrm{Hom}_{D(\operatorname{mod} R)}(\Sigma^{-n-1} M, N)$ to Yoneda $\text{Ext}^1_R(\Omega^n M, N)$ for $R$-modules $M, N$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, let $\operatorname{mod} R$ be the abelian category of finitely generated $R$-modules, and let $D(\operatorname{mod} R)$ be its derived category. Let $M, N \in \operatorname{mod} R$. Choose a projective resolution $P \simeq M$ in $D(\operatorname{mod} R)$. Let $n \ge 0$ be an integer. I am trying to understand the passage from
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}_{D(\operatorname{mod} R)}(\Sigma^{-n-1}  P, N)
  \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D(\operatorname{mod} R)}(\Sigma^{-n-1}  M, N)
$$
to the Yoneda Ext $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R(\Omega^n M, N)$ because I know they are all isomorphic.

My idea is, pick $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{D(\operatorname{mod} R)}(\Sigma^{-n-1}  P, N)$, we have the $\mathrm{cone}(f)$ that fits into an exact sequence $0 \to N \to \mathrm{cone}(f) \to \Sigma^{-n} P \to 0$, now can this exact sequence be somehow naturally identified with an exact sequence $0 \to N \to X_f \to \Omega^n M \to 0$ for some $X_f \in \operatorname{mod} R$?

Please kindly help me to see if this is right, or if this is not, and there is some other natural passage.

(I am a beginner in derived category and triangulated categories, so please forgive me if some of the things I have written is stupid or wrong.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Alex: I know, that's what I have written in my question as well that I know they are all isomorphic, I'm not sure what else you mean ..., I just want to know how to view an element $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{D(\operatorname{mod} R)}(\Sigma^{-n-1}  M, N) $ as a member of the Yoneda Ext $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R(\Omega^n M, N)$

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I do mean Yoneda Ext ... $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $R$ is Noetherian, so $M$ admits a resolution by finitely generated projective $R$-modules, and $\Omega^n M$ is just the $n$-th syzygy in such a projective resolution ... this is a very standard notation for representation theorists(of algebras) and commutative algebraists ...

Comment: @Alex Maybe make this discussion into an answer? Then comments can be cleared...

Comment: @Pedro: Ok, it is now an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take your short exact sequence of complexes $0 \to N \to \mathrm{cone}(f) \to \Sigma^{-n} P \to 0$ and pull it back along map $\Omega^nM \to \Sigma^{-n}P$

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & \xrightarrow{} & N & \xrightarrow{} & \mathrm{cone}(f) & \xrightarrow{} & \Sigma^{-n} P & \xrightarrow{} & 0\\
 &  & \uparrow{=} &  & \uparrow & & \uparrow &  & \\
0 & \xrightarrow{} & N & \xrightarrow{} & T & \xrightarrow{} & \Omega^n M & \xrightarrow{} & 0.\end{array}$$

The long exact sequence of cohomologies gives
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & \xrightarrow{} & H^0(N)=N & \xrightarrow{} & H^0(T)=X_f & \xrightarrow{} & H^0(\Omega^{n} M)=\Omega^n M & \xrightarrow{} & 0.
\end{array}$$